# Leaflet - How to find existing markers, and delete markers?

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I have started using leaflet as an open source map, http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/

The following jQuery code will enable the creation of markers on the map on map click:

```
 map.on('click', onMapClick);
function onMapClick(e) {
        var marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true});
        map.addLayer(marker);
        marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();
};
```

But there is currently no way for me (in my code) to delete existing markers, or find all the markers i've created on a map and put them into an array. Can anyone help me understand how to do this? Leaflet documentation is available here : http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html

Comment: The best way is to create a layergroup. Then we can add markers to layergroup. Layergroup allows to control all markers at once.

Comment: Layer Groups is definitely the cleanest way to handle this. Docs here: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup

Comment: marker.remove();

Comment: Ok, removing the layer seems to be the solution, but the more straightforward answer to the question, how to remove a marker is the one given by @HarijsKrūtainis : marker.remove() , it worked perfectly to me.

Comment: I think using the `new` keyword is redundant since L.marker is a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), see the documentation: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-l-marker

Answer (score 186, accepted):

you have to put your "var marker" out of the function. Then later you can access it :

```
var marker;
function onMapClick(e) {
        marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true});
        map.addLayer(marker);
        marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();
};
```

then later :

```
map.removeLayer(marker)
```

But you can only have the latest marker that way, because each time, the var marker is erased by the latest. So one way to go is to create a global array of marker, and you add your marker in the global array.

Comment: Should be a way to collect all of the layers used by Leaflet. :/

Comment: The layers are internally stored in `map._layers`.

Comment: @jackyalcine: Look at LayerGroup and FeatureGroup

Comment: I think using the `new` keyword is redundant since L.marker is a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), see the documentation: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-l-marker

Answer (score 61):

You can also push markers into an array. See code example, this works for me:

```
/*create array:*/
var marker = new Array();

/*Some Coordinates (here lat lon in json format)*/
var items = [{"lat":"51.000","lon":"13.000"},{"lat":"52.000","lon":"13.010"},{"lat":"52.000","lon":"13.020"}];

/*pushing items into array each by each and then add markers*/
function itemWrap() {
for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    var LamMarker = new L.marker([items[i].lat, items[i].lon]);
    marker.push(LamMarker);
    map.addLayer(marker[i]);
    }
}

/*Going through these marker-items again removing them*/
function markerDelAgain() {
for(i=0;i<marker.length;i++) {
    map.removeLayer(marker[i]);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I think using the `new` keyword is redundant since L.marker is a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), see the documentation: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-l-marker

Answer (score 36):

Here is the code and demo for **Adding the marker**, **deleting any of the marker** and also **getting all the present/added markers** :

Here is the entire [JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/5VLJU/8/) . Also here is the [full page demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/5VLJU/8/embedded/result/).

### Adding the marker :

```
// Script for adding marker on map click
map.on('click', onMapClick);

function onMapClick(e) {

    var geojsonFeature = {

        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]
        }
    }

    var marker;

    L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {

        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){

            marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {

                title: "Resource Location",
                alt: "Resource Location",
                riseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,

            }).bindPopup("<input type='button' value='Delete this marker' class='marker-delete-button'/>");

            marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);

            return marker;
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

---

### Deleting the Marker :

```
// Function to handle delete as well as other events on marker popup open

function onPopupOpen() {

    var tempMarker = this;

    // To remove marker on click of delete button in the popup of marker
    $(".marker-delete-button:visible").click(function () {
        map.removeLayer(tempMarker);
    });
}
```

---

### Getting all the markers in the map :

```
// getting all the markers at once
function getAllMarkers() {

    var allMarkersObjArray = []; // for marker objects
    var allMarkersGeoJsonArray = []; // for readable geoJson markers

    $.each(map._layers, function (ml) {

        if (map._layers[ml].feature) {

            allMarkersObjArray.push(this)
            allMarkersGeoJsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(this.toGeoJSON()))
        }
    })

    console.log(allMarkersObjArray);
}

// any html element such as button, div to call the function()
$(".get-markers").on("click", getAllMarkers);
```

Comment: For getting all markers, `map._layers[ml].feature` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqDKU/) that lets you to create markers using your `onMapClick` method, then delete them by clicking a link.

The process is similar to undefined's - add each new marker to a `markers` array so you can access a specific marker when you want to interact with it later.

Comment: Nice! Only one question, The markers() array still keeps the deleted ones, How would you delete the markers also from the array? Thanks!

Comment: You could use `delete` to remove the item. For example `delete markers[$(this).attr('id')];`.

Comment: The cloudmade API that is included for the tiles in this example seems to be inactive now. Here is a fork that is the exact same, but uses mapquest tile server instead of cloudmade, so no API key needed. http://jsfiddle.net/nqDKU/

Answer (score 8):

(1) add layer group and array to hold layers and reference to layers as global variables:

var search_group = new L.LayerGroup();
 var clickArr = new Array();

(2) add map

(3) Add group layer to map

map.addLayer(search_group);

(4) the add to map function, with a popup that contains a link, which when clicked will have a remove option.  This link will have, as its id the lat long of the point. This id will then be compared to when you click on one of your created markers and you want to delete it.

```
 map.on('click', function(e) {
        var clickPositionMarker = L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng],{icon: idMarker});
        clickArr.push(clickPositionMarker);
        mapLat = e.latlng.lat;
        mapLon = e.latlng.lng;
        clickPositionMarker.addTo(search_group).bindPopup("<a name='removeClickM' id="+e.latlng.lat+"_"+e.latlng.lng+">Remove Me</a>")
                .openPopup();   

                /*   clickPositionMarker.on('click', function(e) {
                  markerDelAgain(); 
                }); */


});
```

(5) The remove function, compare the marker lat long to the id fired in the remove:

```
$(document).on("click","a[name='removeClickM']", function (e) {

      // Stop form from submitting normally
    e.preventDefault();

    for(i=0;i<clickArr.length;i++) {

    if(search_group.hasLayer(clickArr[i]))
    {
        if(clickArr[i]._latlng.lat+"_"+clickArr[i]._latlng.lng==$(this).attr('id'))
            {
                hideLayer(search_group,clickArr[i]);
                clickArr.splice(clickArr.indexOf(clickArr[i]), 1);
            }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add the marker to the layer group, you can apply the `removeLayer` method to the layer group
You need to define the marker variable outside of the function to be able to delete it

```
var marker;
function newMarker() {
 markerLayer = L.layerGroup();
 marker = new L.marker( [12, 13],
 {icon:greenMarker, clickable:true}).bindPopup("Hello Marker").addTo(markerLayer); 

markerLayer.removeLayer(marker);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When you save the reverence to the marker in the adding function the marker can remove it self. No need for arrays.

```
function addPump(){
   var pump = L.marker(cords,{icon: truckPump}).addTo(map).bindPopup($('<a href="#" class="speciallink">Remove ME</a>').click(function() {
            map.removeLayer(pump);
          })[0]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `layerGroup` yet?

Docs here https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layergroup

Just create a layer, add all marker to this layer, then you can find and destroy marker easily.

```
var markers = L.layerGroup()
const marker = L.marker([], {})
markers.addLayer(marker)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a L.Routing.control the answers that include saving the markers in an array will not work. They didn't work for me. I found that the L.Routing.control adds the markers automatically, and removing them is done by removing the L.Routing.control:

```
this.map.removeControl(this.routingControl)
```

The route was removed and all the waypoints/markers, except the first one, and when I console.logged the layers, the layer with waypoints was still there, idk why.

This solution finally worked for me:

```
this.map.eachLayer((layer: any) => {
  if (layer.options.waypoints && layer.options.waypoints.length) {
    this.map.removeLayer(layer);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have various layer groups so that users can show/hide clusters of like type markers.  But, in any case you delete an individual marker by looping over your layer groups to find and delete it.  While looping, search for a marker with a custom attribute, in my case a 'key', added when the marker was added to the layer group.  Add your 'key' just like adding a title attribute.  Later this is gotten an a layer option.  When you find that match, you .removeLayer() and it gets rid of that particular marker.  Hope that helps you out!

```
eventsLayerGroup.addLayer(L.marker([tag.latitude, tag.longitude],{title:tag.title, layer:tag.layer, timestamp:tag.timestamp, key:tag.key, bounceOnAdd: true, icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'vignette', markerColor: 'blue', prefix: '', iconColor: 'white'}) }).bindPopup(customPopup(tag),customOptions).on('click', markerClick)); 

function removeMarker(id){
    var layerGroupsArray = [eventsLayerGroup,landmarksLayerGroup,travelerLayerGroup,marketplaceLayerGroup,myLayerGroup];
    $.each(layerGroupsArray, function (key, value) {
        value.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if(typeof value !== "undefined"){
                if (layer.options.layer){
                    console.log(layer.options.key);
                    console.log(id);
                    if (id === layer.options.key){
                        value.removeLayer(layer);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to remove marker was this create a button who allow me do it

Hope i can help someone :)

```js
//Button who active deleteBool
const button = document.getElementById('btn')

//Boolean who let me delete marker
let deleteBool = false

//Button function to enable boolean
button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  deleteBool = true
})

// Function to delete marker 
const deleteMarker = (e) => {
    if (deleteBool) {
        e.target.removeFrom(map)
        deleteBooly = false
    }
}

//Initiate map
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

//Create one marker
let marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
//Add Marker Function
marker.on('click', deleteMarker)
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#map{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

#btn{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2em auto; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
    <title>MovieCenter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button id="btn">Click me!</button>
    <script script="script" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```