# Leaflet - How to delete arcs from map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So I have a map on which I draw trade routes(as arcs) between countries with [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js). The arcs are different based on the year, and I basically want to be able to redraw the arcs based on what year I pick.

I create the arcs like so:

```
 //for every trade route, draw a arc from start to end 
var line_to_add;
for(var q = 0; q < dest_Coor.length; q++) {
    //create the arc
    var start = {x: from_Coor[0][0], y: from_Coor[0][1]};
    var end = {x: dest_Coor[q][0], y: dest_Coor[q][1]};
    var generator = new arc.GreatCircle(start,end);
    var line = generator.Arc(100, {offset: 10});

    //add it to map 
    line_to_add = L.geoJson(line.json(), {
        color: "#004c00"
    });

    //add the arc to global array of arcs
    allArrows.push(line_to_add);
    line_to_add.addTo(map);
}
```

When a different year is picked, I then try to delete the current arcs through this method, with `allArrows` being a global array of all arc objects(according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912145/leaflet-how-to-find-existing-markers-and-delete-markers)):

```
function deleteOldArcs() {
    for(var i = 0; i < allArrows.length; i++) {
        map.removeLayer(allArrows[u]);
    }
    //then reset the list of arrows:
    allArrows.length = 0;
}
```

However, this doesn't work and program execution just freezes inside `map.removeLayer(allArrows[u])`, and I don't understand why. I checked the list of map layers with `map._layers`, and the arc objects are in there... so why would calling `map.removelayer` not work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several options:

1. Use [Leaflet.Arc](https://github.com/MAD-GooZe/Leaflet.Arc). It will create Leaflet layers directly, which might be easier to manage than the json blobs.
2. Store `line_to_add` somewhere in an array, and call its `remove()` method later. From what I see, you want to reference `allArrows[u]`, but you never fill up the `allArrows` data structure.
3. Use a [`L.LayerGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup). Add the `LayerGroup` to the map, the arcs to the `LayerGroup`, then call its [`clearLayers()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-clearlayers) method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For 2, I think I am trying to do that right? I do `allArrows.push(line_to_add)` in the first code snippet I posted. So why wouldn't that work?  As to 1, I would prefer not to have to change everything unless there is no other choice. As to 3, I don't want to really toggle between layers so it didn't seem like the best option, but I will look into it!

Comment: Hm, then I don't know why the code should hang up. Check the error console, set breakpoints, try to debug what happens when a layer is removed. Oh, and delete removed items from the array, so you don't try to remove already removed items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My error was something very stupid– I used `allArrows[u]` when my iterator is `i`. All the same, I changed things over to Leaflet.Arc, which I think will be nicer to use.