# Remove all marks on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, leaflet

I'm trying to build a tracking driver app using firebase.

I've retrieved all driver data correctly and I make on everyone a marker but I have to know how can I deleted if one of the drivers changes his position to Update it.

My code in Js:

```
var n=0;
var leadsRef = database.ref('Tracking');
leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();

      console.log(" tracking The updated Chauffeur nb " +n +" " + childData.email);
      console.log(" tracking The updated Chauffeur nb " +n+ " "+ childData.latitude);
      console.log(" tracking The updated Chauffeur nb " +n+ " "+ childData.longitude);

      L.marker([parseFloat(childData.latitude), parseFloat(childData.longitude)], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am nb "+childData.email+" hi");
    n++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`child_removed`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#child_removed-event) event to detect when a child of the `Tracking` node is removed.

I don't know leaflet and therefore i don't know how to remove a marker in your case, but I guess there is a specific method for that and, therefore, you could do something along the following lines:

```
ref.on('child_removed', function(oldChildSnapshot) {
  var oldChildData = oldChildSnapshot.val();

  L.removeMarker(...)   //Just inventing a method name here!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `key` and then use `remove()` to delete:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
     database.ref('Tracking').child(key).remove();     
    });
```

Comment: what I need exactly not to delete firebase node or child but I need wheen node or value from my firebase real-time database changes or removed I need to initialise my map(delete all Markers) for update markers positions(add new Markers)

Comment: Then check the duplicate

Comment: but I don't see any posts about how to remove markers with firebase :|

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912145/leaflet-how-to-find-existing-markers-and-delete-markers