# How to display updated markers, leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Good morning all
I would like to have a position tracking with the leaflet.
I managed to display the markers with the positions update every 5 seconds by javascript on an XML file.

I have 2 problems.

The first: the data is well recovered and the markers well positioned, but the markers not being removed from the screen before being re-displayed the old positions remains on the screen.
I tried the technique recommended here ([Leaflet - How to find existing markers, and delete markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912145/leaflet-how-to-find-existing-markers-and-delete-markers?newreg=61a0ebb8c4444daa8570a1464f43d9f6)) but without success. My idea was to do a remove.layer of the markers just before redisplaying them when the position data is up to date.

```
  var personnes = L.layerGroup();

  var map_bus = L.map(
      "map_bus",
      {
          center: [<? echo $_GET['lat'] ?>, <? echo $_GET['lon'] ?>],
          crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
          zoom: 17,
          zoomControl: true,
          preferCanvas: false,
          layers: [personnes]

      }
  );
   var myVar = setInterval(chargerXML, 5000);



   function chargerXML() {
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         myFunction(this);
       }
     };
     xhttp.open("GET", "connectes4.xml", true);
     xhttp.send();
   }
   function myFunction(xml) {
     var i;
     var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
     var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("personne");

     map_bus.removeLayer(personnes);

     for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
       var nomPersonne = x[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
       var latitude = x[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[0].getAttribute("LAT");
       var longitude = x[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[0].getAttribute("LON");
       if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue  == "<? echo $_GET['pseudo'] ?>"){
          marker = L.marker([latitude,longitude], {icon:IconStyleTwo}).bindPopup(nomPersonne);
          marker.addTo(personnes);
       }
       else  {
         marker = L.marker([latitude,longitude], {icon:IconStyleThree}).bindPopup(nomPersonne);
         marker.addTo(personnes);
       }
     }
```

My second problem is to be able to save the position and save it with PHP on the server in an XML file.
I don't know how to articulate javascript with PHP.
Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: If you're using a `L.LayerGroup`, then the first thing to consider would be to run [`clearLayers()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layergroup-clearlayers) on said `LayerGroup`.

Comment: Either one doesn't work :
removeLayer(personnes); personnes.clearLayers();